# Image profile intensity

Tags: python, image, line

Why does the intensity profile of the image which I'm processing not include the right end? I'm supposed to see 7 "peaks" but I don't.

Below is my code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from skimage.measure import profile_line
from skimage.io import imread

start = (0, 714) #Start of the profile line
end = (100, 100) #End of the profile line

#image = imread('....tif') #Read the images
profile = profile_line(image, start, end, linewidth=1, mode='constant') #Take the profile line
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(10, 10)) #Create the figures
ax[0].imshow(image) #Show the film at the top
ax[0].plot(start, end, 'r-', lw=2) #Plot a red line across the film
ax[1].plot(profile)
ax[1].grid()
```

Resulting figure:

[image]

The film which I'm processing:

[image: Film]

Comment: try `start = (100,0)` and `end = (100,714)`

Comment: @Eumel thanks a lot, it seems to work!

Comment: Can you please post two images? One for the one of interest, one for the plot? Can you also turn your code into a proper [mcve]? For example, you shouldn't have a loop to load multiple files.

Comment: Are you open to using numpy or other libraries for this task? It would make your code infinitely simpler.

Comment: `plt.plot(x, y)`, but `skimage.measure.profile_line(image, start, end)`. Your plotted line does not match what you're actually doing and your start and end are not sensible. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I'm using a for loop because there are more than one images which I'm processing. I just haven't showed them. 

Why would you say that the plotted line does not match what I am doing? I want to get the intensity profile along this line on the image. 

I will agree to the fact that the start and end are not sensible but it was the only way I could make it "work".

Comment: @Filippos. Can you post a separate image showing just the image, not an `imshow` of it? I'd like to demonstrate what I'm talking about. Specifically, the line is horizontal in your image, but neither your x nor y coordinates match.

Comment: Also, your plot should show `plot([start[0], end[0]], [start[1], end[1]])`, not what you currently have.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Sure, I don't know how much you can actually see since it's a film. Many thanks.

Comment: You don't use `i` in your loop, so do `for i in images: image = io.imread(i)`. Just the proper way to run a `for` loop, not related to your problem

Comment: @MadPhysicist By the way I understand what you mean for the start and end but that's what made it "work" until that point. I tried other combinations for these parameters but I had no luck. Eumel (above) suggested another way which made it work. I'll modify the code for the for loop. Many thanks.

Comment: @Filippos. If you wait another 15 minutes, I'll have a comprehensive answer with plots and everything. Please don't use `for` loops with imagery. It's just wrong, even if it works.

Comment: OK that took closer to 30 minutes than 15, but I hope it helps you understand what's wrong.

Comment: I rewrote your code to be a proper [mcve]. Please do it like that in the future. Don't post anything that's not relevant to the question you are asking. You can revert the changes if you don't like them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing a bunch of different concepts here. For one thing, your visualization is wrong. [`skimage.measure.profile_line`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.profile_line) accepts two points in `(row, col)` coordinates. [`matplotlib.pyplot.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) accepts two datasets, an `x` and a `y`. By plotting `start` as `x` and `end` as `y`, you are confusing yourself into believing that the line you have is horizontal. Let's take the `x` coordinates (columns) that `profile_line` is cutting from and plot them correctly, and the same for `y` coordinates (rows):

```
start = (0, 714) #Start of the profile line
end = (100, 100) #End of the profile line
image = skimage.io.imread(...)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax[0].set_title('Wrong')
ax[0].imshow(image)
ax[0].plot(start, end, 'r')
ax[1].set_title('Correct')
ax[1].imshow(image)
ax[1].plot([start[1], end[1]], [start[0], end[0]], 'r')
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Hopefully you see that the image labeled "Correct" is showing exactly what you are seeing in your plot.

You can easily correct this. First, let's do it the complicated way: using `profile_line`. You want your start and end y-coordinates to be the same, and the start and end x-coordinates to span the image. Keep in mind that `profile_line` is inclusive on both ends:

```
image = skimage.io.imread(...)

start = (100, 0) #Start of the profile line row=100, col=0
end = (100, image.shape[1] - 1) #End of the profile line row=100, col=last

profile = skimage.measure.profile_line(image, start, end)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax[0].set_title('Image')
ax[0].imshow(image)
ax[0].plot([start[1], end[1]], [start[0], end[0]], 'r')
ax[1].set_title('Profile')
ax[1].plot(profile)
```

[image]

This looks much better. For vertical and horizontal cross-sections, you can obtain identical results using simple [indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html). The images loaded by [`skimage.io.imread`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io#skimage.io.imread) are [numpy arrays](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/absolute_beginners.html#what-is-an-array), so you can just do:

```
profile = image[100, :]
```

For a vertical line, say at column 202, you index along the second (column) axis:

```
profile = image[:, 202]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification/explanation and the answer! Indeed I thought that the line I had was horizontal. Many thanks again.

Comment: Could you please help me with something similar?

Comment: I suggest you ask another question.

Comment: I have, I'm trying to find the best way to contact you and I thought I'd commented here. If you've got some time could you please help me? Many thanks.

Comment: @Filippos. Post a link to the question here and I can take a look.

Comment: Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72463285/using-scipy-peak-width-to-calculate-fwhm-for-a-list?noredirect=1#comment128110281_72463285